# Extract nx.MultiDiGraph values into a dataframe without using nx.to_pandas_edgelist or nx.to_pandas_adjacency

Tags: pandas, dataframe, networkx

I have a `DataFrame` that gives me `edgelist` like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'key' : ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K'],
    'father' : ['A', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'H', 'J'],
    'son' : ['B', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'I', 'K']
})
df

    key     father  son
0   E       A       B
1   E       D       E
2   E       C       D
3   E       B       C
4   K       F       G
5   K       G       H
6   K       I       J
7   K       H       I
8   K       J       K
```

Then I turn it into a `MultiDiGraph` and plot it with this (plotting with `pygraphviz` !) :

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_, 'father', 'son', create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph)
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot, graphviz_layout
plt.title('draw_networkx')
pos =graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, arrows=True)
```

[image: It construct the links just as I wanted !]

It constructs the links just as I wanted ! But I need to get it back into a `DataFrame` in that form, not in `edgelist` format (that would make me going back to my initial input).
It's like I need to extract the values in the right order, and it would give me this result :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key' : ['E', 'K'],
    'step_0' : ['A', 'F'],
    'step_1' : ['B', 'G'],
    'step_2' : ['C', 'H'],
    'step_3' : ['D', 'I'],
    'step_4' : ['E', 'J'],
    'step_5' : [np.NaN, 'K']
})
df2

    key     step_0  step_1  step_2  step_3  step_4  step_5
0   E       A       B       C       D       E       NaN
1   K       F       G       H       I       J       K
```

I don't know well how graphs are structured in `NetworkX`, but I can't do this with `nx.to_pandas_adjacency` or `nx.to_pandas_edgelist`.

In effect, if I turn the graph back to a df with nx.to_pandas_edgelist the output is my input dataframe, at least it would be good if it could give the edgelist in the following order insted of the original one :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key' : ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K'],
    'father' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
    'son' : ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
})
df1

    key     father  son
0   E       A       B
1   E       B       C
2   E       C       D
3   E       D       E
4   K       F       G
5   K       G       H
6   K       H       I
7   K       I       J
8   K       J       K
```

How can I find the values in the right order for each key that is the end of the links, and then extract them into a `DataFrame` by hand ?

Comment: Have you tried to use the `nodelist` parameter of the two methods (you don't want to use)? So simply create a list with the nodes in the desired order and then pass it to the methods. As far as I remember they then use this as iteration order.

Comment: I will try it, but my initial dataframe contains more than 500 graphs to rebuild like this, so I will surely need to automate it. Also, here I putted letters to follow the order because easier to read, but my nodes' ID are non-following 6 or 10 digits strings. I can't manually pass all the nodes in the correct order into the function 500 times to achieve my goal. I tried to get nodelist with `G.nodes` but it gives it to me in the original order too, not in the order showed by the drawing function.

Comment: Check if the ordering of the nodes you want is a topological sort of the nodes (assuming no loops): [`topological_sort`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html)

Comment: I'm going to see if it's the case while running the code. In reality (not just looking at KPI) my network is lots of trees without loops. I come back to you then.